# Migrate a question after it is answered

Tags: discussion

The question in question here was:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/can-i-use-on-when-i-add-the-content

Although the question on this forum was from a person trying to learn English, there were some usage ambiguities in the New York Time article which would have added to the purpose of this forum.

This approach, as suggested in this Meta question ( [Allow Questions to be Closed as Off-Topic and Migrated to ELL](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3750/allow-questions-to-be-closed-as-off-topic-and-migrated-to-ell)), if applied too strictly, risks in making this forum into a 'clubby' and hostile forum.

Yes, questions are sometimes infuriating, but since we are dealing with a subjective area and not an exact science, should there be more leeway?  On a poorly-worded questions, when an attempt has been made to edit the question and someone spots the issue, should it be migrated to ELL?

Or should the migrating moderator attempt to articulate the reason in a comment?

Comment: I don't see anything "hostile" about a migration. If anything, it's usually an attempt to be helpful, and move a question to a forum where it fits better, as seems to have happened in this case.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I have the impression this question/discussion point is predicated on the assumption that migration from ELU to ELL represents some kind of "demotion". Which isn't a point of view I share (nor, presumably, would @J.R., since he actually puts in the extra effort required to be a mod on ELL) The whole *point* of ELL is to help people who are learning English. To my mind, at least, ELU is primarily for people who already know the language, but wish to investigate some of the more obscure points about how and why it has certain features.