# Is it good to migrate questions which are on-topic and have answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, migration, etiquette

Question in question: [What is the difference between an account and an approach?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552652/what-is-the-difference-between-an-account-and-an-approach#comment1367262_552652)

This question is on-topic on ELU and received two answers. The accepted answer says that the usage of "account" is not common, and is better replaced by "model" or "theory". However, I feel that all three words are actually used commonly within the philosophy circle, suggesting that there are specific contexts where "account" is a better word choice than the others. Therefore, I think migrating the question to Philosophy SE would reveal more subtle things that most folks in ELU may not be aware of.

However, one mod said that doing so kind of pooh-poohs the work done by users here. They recommend me asking the question at Philosophy.SE, pointing to this one, explaining how I need a more nuanced answer. I don't object doing that, I just still don't get that why migration is a bad idea in this case.

In Stack Exchange we strive to provide *the best answer* for every question. I suppose users who submitted answers would be happy if they saw a better answer than theirs?

<sub>There is a similar question, but it's [specifically for ELU → ELL migration](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4424/80007).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My reasoning for not migrating is as you have stated.

Mods are advised against migrating questions that are on topic where they currently are and have positively received answers. (Moderators can see this [help article](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/migrating-questions) on migration, point 1. For some reason SE think the details need to be kept secret.)

Thanks to ColleenV for pointing out [this meta meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/273494). The accepted answer has a flow diagram that explains how to make the decision.

[image]
[image]

Since those conditions are met for your question I do not think migrating is a good idea.

Comment: Just a nitpick: the chart doesn't say anything about "pooh-pooh"-ing the work done by the answerers. I just realize that last diamond box in the first chart "Does question already have good answers?" is essential here. And to answer that question, when would an answer be good enough? Surely in my perspective, the existing answers are not good enough - that's why I want to migrate

Comment: My rules of thumb: have they triggered  the auto low quality flag? Have they been flagged as low quality by a human? Do they have a positive score? No no yes. Seems good. Plus one of them is an accepted answer, so is indicated to be helpful. I am not aware of an official baseline for good answers.